# How to delete contact from device objective c APAdressBook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I want to delete a contact from the device I am using the library
[APAdressBook](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook)
I couldn't find deleting a contact in the library documentation.
so is there any way to achieve this?

Any suggestion would be more appreciated.

Update:

So [APAdressBook](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) is not providing delete contact, i am doing with `ABAdressBook` as it a wrapper of it i am getting record id from APAdressBook which i am passing it on `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` which in return gives the contact , finally executing delete record.

```
    APContact *con = duplicateContactsArray[indexPath.row];
            ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

            ABRecordRef contact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressbook,[con.recordID intValue]);
            if (contact) {

                ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressbook, contact, nil);
                ABAddressBookSave(addressbook, nil);
                CFRelease(addressbook);
            }
```

Is this good approach ?

Comment: You are trying to use a private api which is not possible from application. You can do CRUD operations once you fetch the contacts in your application scope.

Comment: @VijaySanghavi what is private api in it?

Comment: @Zack I think you will get some idea from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237332/how-to-delete-record-in-iphone-address-book-using-abaddressbook

Comment: @zack deletion event of address book is private to the native contacts app and the same is not available to use for any other applications.